# How to call an html page on change of checkbox using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onchange

I want a html page to be called when I check a checkbox. I tried the following jQuery code, but it isn't working. What is the mistake I have committed?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#my_checkbox').change(function() {
        alert('Handler for .change() called.');
        $.get("equation_section.html");
        });
</script>
```

And this is my checkbox:

```
 <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox" id="my_checkbox"/>
```

**EDIT**

```
 $('#my_checkbox').change(function() {
if ($('#my_checkbox').attr("checked") == true) {
    alert('Handler for .change() called.');
        $('#my_checkbox').addClass('jQlightbox');
            $.get('equation_section.html', function(data) {
                 $('.equation_section').html(data);
        });
    }
 });
```

This is my edited code. Now I get the alert box. And the page also gets loaded in the div. What if I want only the div content to be displayed upon the modal window and not the previous page content? Someone suggest me please.

Comment: What do you mean by "called"?

Comment: I want the other page, i.e., equation section.html to be loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are (probably) getting the page, but then doing nothing with it. Obviously, you should be looking at sample code from the [jQuery.get() page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Additionally, do you realize this will be called essentially every time the check box get clicked?  If you want to load it the "equation_section.html" page into a div, you could do the following:

In the page:

```
<div id="equation_section"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// on DOM load
$(function () {

  $('#my_checkbox').change(function() {
    alert('Handler for .change() called.');
    $.get('equation_section.html', function(data) {
      $('#equation_section').html(data);
    });
  });

});
</script>
```

If you are trying to redirect the user to the other page, you should do `location.href = "equation_section.html";`

Comment: Make sure you use the `$(function() {});` to execute the code after the DOM loads.

Comment: so that that mean that the change event is not triggered?

Comment: If your alert doesn't happen, then the event handler isn't working.

Comment: Thank you. I got it working after I executed it after the DOM loaded.. See if can help me with this one.. Actually I want this page to open up in a modal window. Previously I had a link with a class "JLightBox", and on clicking that, the modal window with the equation_section.html opened up. Now I need the same to open up on clicking the checkbox.So where do I add this class now?

Comment: You might try to incorporate the jQuery UI dialog (see http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the location of your page to change?  If so you can use `window.location = "equation_section.html"`.  Otherwise you'd have to set the html of a DOM element.

**html**

```
<div id="test_div"></div>
```

**javascript**

```
$("#test_div").load("equation_section.html");
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I want only the div content to be displayed and not the previous page's content?